# vb.net FindByValue

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code

```
     li1 = ddsState.Items.FindByValue("State")
```

I declared li1 as String but says I need as

```
    ListItem.
```

Why?

Comment: Because `ddsState.Items.FindByValue()` returns a `ListItem` and not a `String`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbyvalue.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `ddsState` is a kind of list, perhaps a dropdown list. The `Items` collection consists of `ListItems`. Therefore, when you find one of the `Items`, its type is `ListItem`.

If you change your declaration of `li1` to `ListItem`, you will be able to examine its properties, including its value.